# Regular expression to match url with or without trailing segment

Tags: regex

Trying to build regex expression to match the following url patterns:

`/repos/cflynn07/101/contents/testing
/repos/cflynn07/101/contents/testing?foo=bar
/repos/cflynn07/101/contents/testing/
/repos/cflynn07/101/contents/testing/?foo=bar
/repos/cflynn07/101/contents
/repos/cflynn07/101/contents?foo=bar
/repos/cflynn07/101/contents/
/repos/cflynn07/101/contents/?foo=bar`

Basically a url that optionally has 4 or 5 segments w/ optional query string and trailing forward slash. `cflynn07` and `101` and `testing` segments in example above are dynamic. `repos` and `constants` are consistent.

So far I have:
`^\/repos\/[A-z0-9]+\/[A-z0-9]+\/contents\/[A-z0-9]+?\/?\??.+`

The segment I'm having the most trouble understanding is:
`[A-z0-9]+?` (3rd character set match regex component).

How do I have an optional matching character set within a regex expression? Thanks!

**EDIT**
regexr share: http://www.regexr.com/3a6f4

Comment: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=url&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optionality without making a group:

```
(?:[A-z0-9]+)?
```

But all you need is just:

```
^\/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/){3,5})?(?:[^\/]+)?$
```

Explanation:

```
^                               #start
    \/                          # "/"
    (?:                         #not a group
        (?:                     #not a group
           [a-zA-Z0-9]+\/       #letters, numbers and than symbol "/" 
        ){3,5}                  #3-5 occurrences 
    )?                          #not necessary 
    (?:                         #not a group
        [^\/]+                  #everything but not a symbol "/"
    )?                          #not necessary
$                               #end
```